# How to get factory of an element when element class is not known

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I have a React element and I need to create more elements of the same class. However the class of the element is not known, I just have an instance of the element.

React.createFactory(element) returns undefined. element.**proto** seems to be a ReactClassComponent but haven't figured out how to make a factory out of it. React.createFactory(element.**proto**) returns undefined as well.

Comment: You should use the `__proto__.constructor` rather than the `__proto__`

Comment: @bluehipy works like a charm, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
React.createFactory(element.__proto__.constructor)
```